# Method title raises error

Tags: ruby

I have two methods, one method title `def suche(ins)` somehow raises this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ';' or '\n'
def suche(ins)
```

Im beginner and dont really get what i made wrong!. I hope somebody can help me with this! Thanks a lot

My whole code:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :username, :password, :uid, :private_key, :csr, :certificate

  def initialize(username, password, uid, private_key=nil, csr=nil, certificate=nil)
    @username = username
    @password = password
    @uid = uid
    @private_key = "C:/Sites/keys/#{@username}private.pem"
    @csr = "C:/Sites/keys/#{@username}csr.pem"
    @certificate = certificate
  end

  def send(req,ww,text1=nil,text2=nil)
    @conn = Faraday.new 'https://zombo.de/rest', :ssl => {:verify => false}
    @conn.basic_auth(@username,@password)
    @res = @conn.send(req) do |request| 
      request.url ww
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = text1 unless text1 == nil
      request.body = text2 unless text2 == nil
    end
    puts @res.body
  end

  def login
    send('get',"login/#{@username}")   
  end

  def change_password(newpass)
    send('post',"accounts/#{@uid}/password",'text/plain',"#{newpass}")
  def

  def suche(ins)
    send('get',"accounts/?search=#{ins}") 
  end  

  def send_csr
    send('post','csr','text/plain',"#{File.read(@csr[0..-5])}")
  end

  def get_certificate
    send('get',"accounts/#{@uid}/certificate")   
  end
end

user1 = User.new('john','AAasfsd','896242ß34ß')
user1.get_certificate
```

Comment: I don't get a syntax error for that code

Comment: Ok i will post my whole code! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Stefan I agree with you guys. I stopped editing my answer,as it seems to me that `@conn.send(req)` this part should throw also an error. As `Object#send` will accept its first argument as an symbol or string.

Comment: The code looks fine. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: This can't be the only code necessary to reproduce. The posted code doesn't seem to have any syntax errors.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is this also correct `@conn.send(req) do` ? `#send` without symbol or string as its first parameter.

Comment: Sorry that it took so long to paste all my code! But does somebody know an shortcut to format several lines as code? I always have to push each line!

Comment: @ArupRakshit it's not the source of `SyntaxError`, even if it is the problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, you post code "as is", then select it and click on button with curly braces icon in SO editor.

Comment: @JohnSmith please paste the whole error backtrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method just before `suche`, you have a `def` where it should be an `end`.

Comment: Yes.. you used your eyes finally... :)